# Re-rendering an EJS template after jQuery POST request with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

**Update** Edited my original code due to errors.

This is my first question posted here so please be gentle. :)

I am using node.js with Express and EJS forms.

What I am trying to achieve is to have an EJS template re-rendered after a jQuery POST request with new data. This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do (my original code includes a lot of fuss, SQL queries and is not properly refactored).

My goal would be to render the **same** template with different data when pressing a button on the page. What happening currently is when I press the button, the data **is there** (checking it in console), but the page does not render again with the new data. I am completely out of ideas and been stuck with this for almost a day now.

I know I could do something like

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

and build the HTML with a JS script, but it would be nice to be able to use EJS for better readability - my original code includes a lot of HTML elements.

Is it doable at all? Or is this an intended behaviour for rendering with Express? Sorry if I am being clueless, as I am fairly new to web development.

Anyway, here is my code, all ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**test_dynamic.ejs**:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/test">
    <wrapper>
        <h1>
            <button id="toggleButton" onclick="toggle()" type="button">Toggle</button>
        </h1>
        <div>
            <% console.log('Should show ' + name + ' with id: ' + id) %> 
            <li><%=name  %></li>
            <li><%=id  %></li>
        </div>
    </wrapper>
</form>
</html>
<script>
    var shouldShowJohn = false;
    function toggle () {
        var postData = {};
        shouldShowJohn = !shouldShowJohn;
        if (shouldShowJohn)
            postData.mode = 1;
        else
            postData.mode = 2;
        $.post('http://localhost:3000/test', postData, function (data) {
            $('#toggleButton').html('').append('Showing ' + postData.mode);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**routes.js**:

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) =>{
  var obj = {
    name: 'DefaultName',
    id: 1
  }
  res.render('test_dynamic', obj);
})

router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  var obj = {};
  console.log('req.body.mode: ' + req.body.mode);
  if (req.body.mode == 1)
    obj = {
      name: 'John',
      id: 2
    }
  else
    obj = {
      name: 'Karl',
      id: 3
    }
  res.render('test_dynamic', obj)
})
```

Comment: The issue is that a POST request is not a GET request, so your browser will not re-load the page. The workflow is: 1. Send POST, 2. Response with success/failure 3. If success, redirect/re-request same page from server.

Comment: Randy, thanks for your reply! How can I respond with success/failure? Any docs/tutorial you could point me to?

Comment: Well written question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, partially based on Randy's answer.

**test_dynamic.ejs:**

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="myBody">
<form method="post" action="/test">
    <wrapper>
        <h1>
            <button id="toggleButton" onclick="toggle()" type="button">Toggle</button>
        </h1>
        <div>
            <% console.log('Should show ' + name + ' with id: ' + id) %> 
            <li><%=name  %></li>
            <li><%=id  %></li>
        </div>
    </wrapper>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var shouldShowJohn = false;
    var postData = {};
    postData.mode = 'toggle';
    function toggle () {
        $.post('http://localhost:3000/test', postData, function (data) {
            $('#toggleButton').html('').append('Showing ' + postData.mode);
            $('#myBody').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**routes.js:**

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) =>{
  var obj = {
    name: 'DefaultName',
    id: 1
  }
  res.render('test_dynamic', obj);
})

var currentMode = 1;
router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    var obj = {};
    console.log('req.body.mode: ' + req.body.mode);
    if (req.body.mode == 'toggle')
        if (currentMode < 3)
            currentMode++;
        else
            currentMode = 1;
  if (req.body.mode == 1)
    obj = {
      name: 'John',
      id: 2
    }
  else
    obj = {
      name: 'Karl',
      id: 3
    }
  res.render('test_dyanmic', obj)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the example I've included via link below. There is a lot wrong with your HTML above, but I will focus on your question. There are several ways you can solve this problem so this is the simplest.

As stated in my comment, the workflow is:

1. Send POST
2. Respond with success/failure
3. If success, redirect/re-request same page from server.

Note I am not addressing EJS because when you request the page from the server that will happen naturally as you have laid out above.

**Step 1**: So in the sample, `index.js` is the server, I have basic routing to two files, `index.html` and `page2.html`. I did this so you can see the change happening. Next, in the `index.html` file I have a button that generates the POST request via jQuery. This takes care of step 1.

**Step 2**: `index.js` accepts the post request to `/test` and responds with a simple string "success" (you could respond with anything)

**Step3**: In `index.html` the `$.post()` handler tests for the string 'success' and the redirects to `page2.html`. In your scenario this would redirect back to the same page. I made it different so you could realize the change easily.

***Solution***

https://repl.it/@randycasburn/SimplePostResponseRedirect

Comment: All right Randy, thanks for the thorough explanation. Will look into it and get back to you - if this solves the problem, I will mark your advise as solution.

Comment: Hello Randy, thanks for taking the time to explain. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue, as my goal was to re-render the template with different data, not simply reload the same page.